# CreateDIBSection failed

Tags: c++, gdi, createdibsection

```
BITMAPINFO bmi;
memset(&bmi,0,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize            = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth           =m_pImg->GetWidth();
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight          =m_pImg->GetHeight();
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes          = 1;
//if(   m_pImg->GetInfo()->biBitCount!=16)  
//{
//  bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount    =   m_pImg->GetInfo()->biBitCount;
//}
//else 
//{
//ASSERT((m_pImg->GetInfo())->bmiHeader->biBitCount == 24);
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount=24;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression     = BI_RGB;
if (bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage == 0)
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage =
    WidthBytes(bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth,bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount) * bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight;
if(bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed == 0 && bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount <16)
    bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed=DWORD(1 <<bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount);
m_nNewSize=bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;

if(m_hbmCanvasBitmap!=NULL)
{
    DeleteObject(m_hbmCanvasBitmap);
    m_hbmCanvasBitmap=NULL;
    m_pCanvasBits=NULL;
}
//  创建直接与DC相关联的位图
m_hbmCanvasBitmap=CreateDIBSection(m_hDC, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS,(void**)&m_pCanvasBits, NULL, NULL);
```

// after CreateDIBSection
I found the error code is 8, no enough resource.

How can I avoid this error?
I pass width: 3500 height 2500
many thanks!

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442162/stretchdibits-failed-sometimes-it-draw-nothing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer to this is the same as the answer to your earlier question:  your bitmaps are *way* too big.

Also, since your dimensions are now half the dimensions of the bitmap in your earlier question, I'm guessing you're trying to break the destination up into quadrants, but now you don't have enough resources to even create the destination bitmap.  This may mean that you're also not releasing the bitmap memory from your previous attempts.  You may want to reboot and try all this again with *much* smaller destination images.

Answer (score 0):

There simply isn't enough memory to complete your command. You can't "fix" it as is, except to try and break some memory boundary.

Rather, you need to split whatever image your working on into manageable sizes, so they can be swapped in and out.